# Unable to load server class 'com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher'

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using Google Plugin for eclipse to develop website using GWT. Every thing work properly before. Today I installed a theme plugin for eclipse and i uninstall this theme plugin after that. When i run my gwt project I get the error

> Unable to load server class 'com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher'
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher

I have tried reinstall Google Plugin for Eclipse and i still get this error.
How to solve this error ? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried reinstall eclipse and the Google Plugin. Everything work ok.